# how to get a Spring bean that is local to the current HttpRequest

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I would like to be able to create a bean whose scope is limited to the currently serviced HttpRequest.

I considered `ThreadLocal` but the problem I see is that threads can be reused to service an HttpRequest by the container.  I would like to use said bean in a bean that has no concept of the currently serviced HttpRequest.  Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use request-scoped beans: [3.5.4. Request, session, and global session scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other)